# HOw to add new column from another file in awk

Tags: linux, awk

I have two files like shown below which are tab-delimited:

file A

```
123,789   aa b c d
123       aa b c d
234       a  b c d
345       aa b c d
456       a  b c d
....
```

file B

```
123    add    c    d    e
345    add   e    f    g
789    sub   e    f    g
...
```

I want to add column 2 from file B to file A based on column 1 such that output looks as shown below:
output:

```
123,789   add,sub  aa b c d
123        add     aa b c d
234                a  b c d
345        add     aa b c d
456                a  b c d
....
```

I tried using:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next}{$2=a[$1]FS$2;print}' OFS='\t' fileB file A
```

which gives the output:

```
123,789            aa b c d
123        add     aa b c d
234                a  b c d
345        add     aa b c d
456                a  b c d
```

The problem is with columns having multiple strings separated by comma in column1 of file A. The awk code treats it is a single string due to which it cannot match with fileB. Could someone give an edit to awk code or any fix. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say

```
awk -F '\t' 'BEGIN { OFS = FS } NR == FNR { saved[$1] = $2; next } { n = split($1, a, ","); sep = ""; field = ""; for(i = 1; i <= n; ++i) { if(a[i] in saved) { field = field sep saved[a[i]]; sep = "," } } $1 = $1 OFS field } 1' fileB fileA
```

That is:

```
BEGIN { OFS = FS }                  # Output separated like input

NR == FNR {                         # while processing fileB:
  saved[$1] = $2                    # just remember stuff
  next
}

{                                   # while processing fileA:
  n = split($1, a, ",")             # split first field at commas

  sep   = ""                        # reset temps
  field = ""

  for(i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {         # wade through comma-separated parts of $1
    if(a[i] in saved) {             # if a corresponding line existed in fileB
      field = field sep saved[a[i]] # append it to the new field
      sep = ","                     # from the second forward, separate by ","
    }
  }

  $1 = $1 OFS field                 # insert the new field into the line
}
1                                   # then print.
```

Comment: Basically the same as mine, but complete with explanation. Feel free to take any bits you like from mine - I would recommend changing the third argument to split to `/,/`. Also I think the point is to overwrite the second field rather than insert the new field before it. Pretty easy just to change `field` to `$2`.

Comment: @TomFenech The `aa` fields still appear in the example output. Unless I'm being blind (which would, admittedly, not be without precedent), a new field is supposed to be inserted. The `/,/` thing seems like a matter of taste to me. I suppose an argument could be made that `/,/` makes it more visible that the argument to `split` is a regex, but I subjectively find it to be less readable.

Comment: Ah yes, you're right about inserting the field. I guess the argument in favour of using a regex is that you save poor awk from having to convert the string for you, costing a few cycles :-)

Comment: I hope that most awks only do that once at the beginning. I should probably benchmark it one of these days.

Comment: I applied it to real data where i have to add 3 columns from fileB  as `awk -F '\t' 'BEGIN { OFS = FS } NR == FNR { saved[$1] = $2FS$3FS4; next } { n = split($1, a, ","); sep = ""; field = ""; for(i = 1; i <= n; ++i) { if(a[i] in saved) { field = field sep saved[a[i]]; sep = "," } } $1 = $1 OFS field }1' fileB fileA`    Then counted the total cloumns after adding `awk -F "\t" "{print NF}" | sort | uniq`  which showed unequal columns. It is adding only the columns which has some string in fileB i.e. ignoring the columns with empty field which results in unequal number of columns in each row.

Comment: @chas If you want to do this for several input columns, you'll have to assemble the new fields separately (i.e., `saved1[$1] = $2; saved2[$1] = $3; saved3[$1] = $4`, then later `field1 = field1 sep saved1[a[i]]; ... $1 = $1 OFS field1 OFS field2 OFS field3` The way you're doing it, you'll add a comma-separated list of records of three fields each for every match. You may want to do that in a loop each time with `saved[i,$1]` for two-dimensional array access.